# How change 2 different UI text via C# script in Unity 4.6

Tags: c#, text, unity-game-engine, textbox

I'm trying to change two different text fields in Unity 4.6.3 with C# in monodevelop.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NumberWizard : MonoBehaviour {
    int max;
    int min;
    int guess;
    public Text GuessUI;
    public Text TextUI;

                       [...truncated...]

        GuessUI.text = "500"; 
        TextUI.text = "Welcome to Number Wizard!";
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
NumberWizard.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/NumberWizard.cs:16)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: If you get an exception in some method, it's usually a good idea to include the body of said method in the question. Is the code that you included from the `Start` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figured out why that wasn't working but now is solved:

```
public Text GuessUI;
public Text TextUI;

TextUI.text = "Welcome to Number Wizard!";
GuessUI.text = "500";
```

And I set up this in inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not so clear what you want to achieve but if you want to update Text with depend on something then you should use IF statement. If you want to update 2 Text then NumberWizard script should take 2 Text parameters. Alternatively, you can use GameObject.FindByName() method.
Example:

```
TextUI = GameObject.FindByName("TextUI");
GuessUI = GameObject.FindByName("GuessUI");
TextUI.Text = "Test1";
GuessUI.Text = "Test2";
```

Note: Your code and screenshots doesn't match. If you've 2 Text components then Unity Editor should show them.

Comment: Sorry, my current computer doesn't have Unity. Can you show me the error code if any?